# Azure synapse External Table - Parameterise location

Tags: azure-synapse, external-tables

Is it possible to pass a parameter(date) to the location of the Azure Synapse External Table?

LOCATION='/Windows/Folder/File_name_yyyy-MM-dd.csv'

I want to parameterise yyyy-MM-dd and File_name_yyyy-MM-dd.csv as a parameter which changes every day. I tried all below, but nothing allows me to create the table due to syntax errors -

```
LOCATION->'/Windows/Folder/File_name_'format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')'.csv'
LOCATION->'/Windows/Folder/File_name_'{format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}'.csv'
LOCATION->'/Windows/Folder/File_name_'@{format(getdate(),'yyyy-MM-dd')}'.csv'
```

Comment: No.  You could use dynamic SQL to achieve similar effect.

Comment: Are you able to help me out here, if you have an example for this scenario using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Yes, of course!  You should read this article on [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and then you will be ready!